# Parallel Autonomic regulation of Cough and Runny Nose

Tags: pathophysiology, autonomic-nervous-system

I describe [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/16984/86) the serous inflammation of runny nose.
Cough is mediated by Cough center.

I think Runny nose is also controlled by the autonomic nervous system and probably by some reflex.

Assume you have mild runny nose under Montelukast medication.
You have **irritated cough** (coughing so much you cannot sleep).
You stop the cough by codeine before sleeping.
You sleep at 30 degree angle.
Sometimes, you also feel that the runny nose stops i.e. **complete relieve of runny nose in both nostrils and whole nose** for about 30 seconds to a minute - perfectly clear nose and no serous inflammation - no symptoms of imflammation in the nose.

Then, it (serous inflammation) starts again - not like mucose running back - but the feeling of uneasiness in the whole nose starts again - then mucose can also continue to migrate from one nostril to another.
**What is causing this kind of behaviour i.e complete relieve of of runny nose for about 30 seconds?**
**What is causing the stopping of serous inflammation in the nose?**

I think the Runny nose can also be controlled by medulla oblongata because Codeine is blocking the cough center there.

I tried to achieve this behaviour by stimulating by lymphatic system in regulating breathing by abdominal muscles - lymphatic drainage massage - breathing inside with abdomen (not with thorax) and deeply exhale with abdomen).
At that time, I did not hear any creaky sounds in my throat.
After trying to stop the serous inflammation again, I heard them without managing to stop serous inflammation in both nostrils at the same time.

**How is the control of Cough and Runny nose regulated by the autonomic nervous system?**
Probably, some parallelism there.

Processes going on regulating Cough and Runny nose

- reflex from medulla oblongata
- sympaticus and parasympaticus (not sure about these)
- possible parallelism of irritated cough and runny nose control

Comment: From my experience (and what my kids doctors told me) most of the coughing connected with a cold (especially the sort which occurs at night when you lay down) comes from the mucus which is coming from the sinuses and is moving around due to the changed body position and thus causing problems.

Comment: @Chris That is different story. Moving mucose in the nose between nostrils and completely relieve of runny nose (you do not feel anymore the serous inflammation process at all).

Comment: To add to your idea of a link between cough and runny nose: Codein binds to opioidreceptors. A runny nose is known to be one of the early symptoms of opioid withdrawal.

Answer (score 1):

Skymninge mentioned opioidreceptors and the withdrawal symptom of opiods as a runny nose: codein binds to opioidreceptors.

I think now that the cough can trigger runny nose.
I breathed with empty nose some 15 minutes.
Then, I had a deep dry cough and right after it a stuffy nose.
I really felt this time the negative gradient at the level of kidneys and also posteriorly.
I do not know how this kind of pain was felt, I think, near or on the kidneys.
I do not understand the effects of deep dry coughs.
They seem to be linked to several processes and locations in the body.

After this deep dry cough, I did some abdominal breathes and this way massaging the lymphatic circulation systemically, the stuffy nose disappeared.
My thorax is opposite of astonic person (say if you remember the name in Propedeutics).
This can be a restricting factor in the circulation of the lymph.

My conjecture is that the people with big chests (opposite of astonic) need to concentrate more on abdominal breathing such that to keep out of stuffy noses.
Restricted lymphatic circulation causes less wastes returned to the blood circulation.
Thus, accumulation of bacteria in the larynges which increases the risk of a dry cough.
Good lymphatic circulation ensures that bacteria is not congested in the larynx.
So **cough seems to be a mechanism to start a runny nose**.

This all is finely regulated.
There are several receptors in the body.
The deep cough however seems to be linked to a reflex which causes a runny nose.

Some studies about opiates and respiratory activity

- [The effects of opiates on the respiratory activity of thoracic motoneurones in the anaesthetized and decerebrate rabbit.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1890632)